# How to download a file that is inside the component folder from the dialog?

Tags: javascript, jsp, aem

I'm looking for how to download a file that is inside the component folder from the dialog using a download button for example.

If the user opens for the first time the component dialog, then this will need a file example, I need to give to the user an option to download that example.

path example:

- component_folder

  - component.jsp
  - resources_folder

    - example.txt

Some suggestion?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Hi @Davidlrnt, I already tried that but link tag can not access to the component folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Publish, there wont be any anonymous access to /apps hierarchy. The ideal way to implement this is -

- Put your file to be downloaded in `/content/dam` hierarchy or any custom hierarchy under content that can be accessed via anonymous on publish
- Update your dialog box to use a path field to configure the path to above file
- Your down action should not use the path configured in the dialog and download from that path instead of `/apps/.../yourcomponent/file_name`.

This method is secure and doesn't expose your apps hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, and the last option create a servlet that returns the file and call it using ajax from the dialog, right?

Comment: I don't think you need to do that, if directly clicked and browser understands the format it will open it or give end user an option to download it. If you want to provide download only provision then you can go via servlet route